# How to manipulate scheme binary trees

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write a scheme program that inputs a specific depth of a binary tree. For example, the root of a binary tree is 1 and then the root of the left sub tree is 2 and so on and on. I am supposed to make it output the data expression that has the depth in the tree. Right now I have the code below, but I am continuously getting error message:

```
Error in null?: expected a list; got '1'.
```

If you could explain this using the same terms in the code that I am using it would be great as I am learning and I do not know how to use some of the bigger expressions.

This is the code

```
(define fetch-exp
  (λ (n bt)
    (cond [(empty-tree? bt) ▽#f]
          [(> n (tree-depth (left-tree bt))) ▽#f]
          [(> n (tree-depth (right-tree bt))) ▽#f]
          [(one? n) (root bt)]
          [(> (tree-depth (left-tree bt)) (tree-depth (right-tree bt)))
           (fetch-exp (left-tree bt) (sub1 n))]
          [(> (tree-depth (right-tree bt)) (tree-depth (left-tree bt)))
           (fetch-exp (right-tree bt) (sub1 n))]
          [else ▽#f])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting the depth of each child is going to take forever as it is itself a tree traversal. In addition you potentially  do it twice for each side. It would be better to bind the result in a let statement if you have to do it that way. (Or anywhere where you do a case analysis and use the result of a potential expensive evaluation more than once, for that matter). Otherwise revise the program such that it only evaluates it once.

```
(define (fetch-exp n bt)
  (cond ((empty-tree? bt) #f)
        ((= 1 n) (root bt))
        (else (or (fetch-exp (sub1 n) (left-tree bt)) 
                  (fetch-exp (sub1 n) (right-tree bt))))))
```

This like yours will just go down the left branches. If it fails the or statement on the stack keep trying until it find an appropriate data item or reach the very  bottom right branch  of the tree. In the very worse case you end up traversing the tree once, which is actually the very best case for your process in a non-empty tree, as you walk the tree even before checking if n is 1.

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there any way to create the same function without using "or"

Comment: Yes, change the replace else clause with two clauses instead ((fetch-exp (sub1 n) (left-tree bt))) (else (fetch-exp (sub1 n) (right-tree bt))) One clause cond clauses are legal, and if the clause is anything but false it returns that value, But this is also a bit ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Your major problem is that your recursive calls into `fetch-exp` swapped the order of the arguments. It should be `(fetch-exp (sub1 n) (left-tree bt))` and `(fetch-exp (sub1 n) (right-tree bt))`. Alternatively, change the function's parameter order: `(lambda (bt n) ...)`.